# What is '0x0' address in Solidity (Ethereum)?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm studying solidity programming, and I have a question on this line of code:

`Transfer(0x0,msg.sender,tokens);`

I don't understand what `0x0` means. Is it the new token address or is it the new smart contract's address?

Comment: ransfer(0x0,msg.sender,tokens);  => Transfer(0x0,msg.sender,tokens); Sorry to miss it.

Comment: You can edit the question if you want.

Comment: Check this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/18427

Answer (score 16):

`0x0` is essentially a black hole of an address. Ether funds go in, none come out (kind of like a marriage!). It's an abbreviation for the genesis address [0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), which with almost absolute certainty nobody has the private key for, so it can't be spent. Note that **tokens** like ERC20 can be transferred OUT depending on the contract, but not Ether.

Amusingly/tragically a lot of people screw up and [send money here by accident](https://www.2100news.com/2018/03/05/590-million-mistakenly-sent-ethereums-genesis-address/).

In your case, it looks like the contract is trying to send money to this address. Apparently, there's some use cases for this called "proof of burn" which I guess means that you can send ether? I don't quite understand that as it's literally taking Ether out of circulation.

Other cases can be for using it as a large amount for an address for comparison. Example is `your_ETH_balance < 0x0` (Is ***probably*** TRUE).

Currently, `0x0` has 7251 ether (and growing since I started typing). Today's trading puts it worth about $4.2 million, so it'd be one of the more valuable addresses to crack if you happen to have a functional quantum computer (which you don't).

Comment: kind of like a marriage xD

Comment: 15 months since my original answer, `0x0` has increased by 528 Ether, however due to the price reduction, the current balance in USD is *ONLY* $1.714 million. Also amusing if you look on EtherScan comments, you'll see people still continue to make donation requests. *"Please help me, I am from xyz... my ether address is... "*

Comment: Checking back in on this post over three years later... the total burned ETH lost to this address is now valued at $16 million, with an additional 1 million in other tokens.  

Comment: "which you don't" you don't know me

Comment: @JakeSmith $18,815,443 says you don't....

Comment: @pgSystemTester touche ;-)