# Near protocol equivalent of buring NEAR tokens by sending to address(0)

Tags: nearprotocol

I want to delete the current contract and burn its NEAR balance when a condition is triggered.

Here's the Solidity version:

```
selfdestruct(address(0));
```

I found `Promise::delete_account` in the [Rust SDK](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/9d99077c6acfde68c06845f2a1eb2b5ed7983401/near-sdk/src/promise.rs#L309) but it has a `beneficiary_address` field. Ideally the funds should be gone forever and not transferred to an owned address.

```
Promise::new(env::current_account_id()).delete_account(beneficiary_address);
```

`address(0)` is [address `0x0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580769/what-is-0x0-address-in-solidity-ethereum), a black hole address used to burn Ether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no API to burn NEAR tokens directly. One workaround is to set the beneficiary account id to `system`. `system` is an account that can never be created and is used internally for refunds. When the beneficiary account does not exist, the tokens transferred through account deletion are automatically burnt.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is like this:

```
#[payable]
pub fn burn() {  
 Promise::new("system".to_string()).transfer(env::attached_deposit());
}
```

First importing:

```
use near_sdk::{Promise};
```